# Adding 1 required field on the content version object

Tags: files, contentversion

So right now I have a contentversion that I want to put in an additional field. If I did not put the required on the field I can  successfully upload a file but the file just uploads and there isn't any next Button. If I put the field as required I am not able to upload any files anymore.

May I ask what is the right way to do this ?

EDIT:
If I open the dev console, it is saying success.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it is not possible to use the required custom fields on the content version object with the default upload.

you have 2 options:

1. customize the upload, using a flow, Aura, or LWC.
2. auto-fill that information using pre-existing data in salesforce, using a trigger.

My guess is that you will need to create a custom upload.

Answer (score 0):

We can't Expose custom fields on ContentVersion when uploading files.

Refer the [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdc4LUAR/expose-custom-fields-on-contentversion-when-uploading-files)